# Django - <ul> content from db is not rendered as HTML, is pure text

Tags: html, django

Not sure what is wrong here. I have some html content in my tables.

Table column:

```
 (ul)(li)one(/li)(li)two(/li)(li)three(/li)(/ul)
```

Template:

```
(div class="plst")
(p)Pros:(/p)
{{ review.plist }}
(/div)
```

**Please replace the () with <>**

In the output i am seeing

```
 (ul)(li)one(/li)(li)two(/li)(li)three(/li)(/ul)
```

as such and not

```
onetwothree
```

Don't know what is happening here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you turned autoescape on?

Comment: What's that? I don know :(

Comment: use {{ review.plist|safe }}

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `safe` template tag filter.

```
<div class="plst">
<p>Pros:</p>
{{ review.plist | safe }}
</div>
```

The `safe` filter turns off escaping of <, >, and &.  With escaping off, they are passed straight through to the output.